# Increase parameter in column of table

Tags: mysql, groovy

Please, help me to make a script which will increase a number in column "number" in MySQL database as i  pictured below:

```
******************
* index * number *
******************
* 1000A *  01    *
* 1000B *  02    *
* 1000C *  03    *
* 1000D *  04    *
… 
* 1000Z *  99    *
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
update `mytable` set number = number + 1 where index = $YOUR_INDEX;
```

Replace `$YOUR_INDEX` with the index of interest, of course.